# how to capture the content inside nested brackets

Tags: regex

I have the following text wrapped by a `ExclusifyUnion<>` type. What I want is removing with a regex that wrapper and leave what's inside its major-minor brackets.

If it helps, every type declaration will have a final `>;\n`. I though of a negative lookahead but with no results:

```
type A = ExclusifyUnion<Omit<SwitchRowContentProps, 'switch'> & {
    switch: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | (Omit<CheckboxRowContentProps, 'checkbox'> & {
    checkbox: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | OnPressRowContentProps | BasicRowContentProps | RadioRowContentProps | HrefRowContentProps | ToRowContentProps>;

type B = ExclusifyUnion<BasicBoxedRowProps | (Omit<SwitchBoxedRowProps, 'switch'> & {
    switch: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | RadioBoxedRowProps | (Omit<CheckboxBoxedRowProps, 'checkbox'> & {
    checkbox: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | HrefBoxedRowProps | ToBoxedRowProps | OnPressBoxedRowProps>;
```

The final result I wanna get:

```
type A = Omit<SwitchRowContentProps, 'switch'> & {
    switch: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | (Omit<CheckboxRowContentProps, 'checkbox'> & {
    checkbox: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | OnPressRowContentProps | BasicRowContentProps | RadioRowContentProps | HrefRowContentProps | ToRowContentProps;

type B = BasicBoxedRowProps | (Omit<SwitchBoxedRowProps, 'switch'> & {
    switch: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | RadioBoxedRowProps | (Omit<CheckboxBoxedRowProps, 'checkbox'> & {
    checkbox: ControlProps | undefined;
}) | HrefBoxedRowProps | ToBoxedRowProps | OnPressBoxedRowProps;
```

Comment: Maybe it suffices if you capture in each block what's between the first `ExclusifyUnion<` and the last `>` and replace the full match with the capture. With the assumption, that blocks are separated by lines containing nothing or only whitespace. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VHbuXr/1).

Comment: Btw when asking regex questions related to recursion it's mandatory to mention the tool/lang using. See [this neat overview](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) where regex recursion can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that `ExclusifyUnion` would always occur at the top level and at most once for each type assignment, we can try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    /ExclusifyUnion<((?:(?!\b\w+(?: \w+)* =).)*)>;/gms
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

The above regex pattern uses a tempered dot trick to ensure that each match continues up to, but not including, the proceeding type assignment line.